# Is the acoustic wave equation valid in flowing water or when air is moving? (Wikipedia derivation assumes fluid is at reset)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics

The [Wikipedia derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_theory#Assumption_1:_Newtonian_fluid) of the acoustic wave equation makes the assumption that the fluid is at rest. But then this would mean that the acoustic wave equation is not valid when a fluid (such as air or water) is moving! So am I missing something here? Do we need another equation to describe acoustic wave propagation when the wind is blowing or when water is flowing?

Comment: If the entire body of fluid is moving as one whole (i.e. with no relative velocity between its distinct parts) then you can simply switch to the reference frame in which the fluid is at rest and apply the usual acoustic equation.

Comment: So if the fluid is accelerating the acoustic equations are invalid? This seems to invalidate the acoustic equations for a huge number of real world situations. The most glaring one being, using the acoustic equation for sound propagation in air that governs the sounds we listen to everyday. Right now there is a fan blowing air at me in an office. So is normal acoustic equation for wave propagation not appropriate for modelling the sounds I am currently hearing?

Comment: What I meant to say was that the acoustic equation derived for fluid at rest is also applicable to fluid in uniform motion. For other cases the acoustic equation may be modified. This might help: https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5562